# How to keep perl file executable after brunch build?

Tags: perl, file-permissions, brunch

We've developed a website with brunch, and now we face a problem.

An executable (permisson mode:755) perl script is in the folder app/assets/.
After I execute brunch build, the resultant perl script isn't executable any more, and can't be called by CGI.
Besides chmod after build or creating soft link, is there any other solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brunch provides a hook called `onCompile` that allows plugins to run arbitrary code after a compile. [This brunch plugin](https://github.com/SomeHats/oncompile-brunch/blob/master/index.coffee) seems like it would be useful as a crib-sheet. Create a plugin that fixes up permissions for your files.

Answer (score 0):

Change `"app/assets/YourScript.pl"` to `"/usr/bin/perl app/assets/YourScript.pl"`.

Comment: But we need to execute it by ajax call.